# Why does this Haskell program diverge?

Tags: haskell

Looks like a strange difference between [1,2,3] and [1..3].

Using runghc on the following prints out one "True" and then hangs forever: why? (I'm using ghc 7.8.3)

```
module Main where

import Data.Functor((<$>))
import Data.Time.Clock(DiffTime)
import Data.Binary(Binary(..), encode, decode, Get)
import Data.Int(Int64)

instance Binary DiffTime where
  put x = put (truncate (x * 10^12) :: Int64)
  get = ((/ 10^12) . fromIntegral) <$> (get :: Get Int64)

prop_getput_difftime :: DiffTime -> Bool
prop_getput_difftime x = x == ((decode . encode $ x) :: DiffTime)

explicit :: [DiffTime]
explicit = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

elipsis :: [DiffTime]
elipsis = [1..10]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ all prop_getput_difftime explicit
  print $ all prop_getput_difftime elipsis -- diverges!
```

---

Note, the above implementation of Binary for DiffTime is wrong; but that is beside the point.

Comment: What happens if you swap the statements?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to otulp from #haskell, here's the reason:

```
Prelude> take 3 [1..2] :: [Data.Time.DiffTime]
[1s,1.000000000001s,1.000000000002s]
```

Which happens because of the `Enum` instance for `DiffTime`

Changing `elipsis` to this fixes the problem:

```
elipsis = map fromIntegral ([1..10] :: [Int])
```

Comment: @PeterWortmann, nice! Though for future-proofing it against unaware maintainers, that solution is a bit more obscure.

Comment: That `Enum` instance itself is extremely obscure.

Comment: Both of these "fixes" look rather fragile to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: [..] is a big pitfall regardless. `[x..y]` should have type `Integral a => [a]` and there should be another function, `enumAll :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]`

Comment: For future reference, whenever the ellipsis give you issues, remember that it's just syntactic sugar for `Enum`, so under all scenarios that's where you'd want to be looking and making sure everything's okay. By the by, I'm perfectly happy with `Enum`.